# When clicking the Edit/Delete button, It always gets or editing/delete the last record

Tags: php, laravel

Whenever I am clicking the edit/delete button, the one that's being edited or deleted is the last record from the database. I am deleting/editing the records via the userId.This is the code that I have a problem with in my users.blade.php. The other files are accessible thru the link.

users.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>User Management</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../res/css/asset_information.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../res/css/navbar.css"> 
</head> 

<body> 
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-bar"> 
      <button class="notification-button">
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i> <!-- Bell icon -->
      </button>

      <div id="menuToggle" class="toggle-menu active">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div id="sideMenu" class="side-menu">
        <div class="menu-items">
          <a href="#" class="item">Dashboard</a>
          <a href="{{ route('admin/users') }}" id="active_tab" class="item1">Users</a>
          <a href="#" class="item" id="active_tab">Asset Management</a>
          <a href="{{ route ('admin/pending')}}" class="item1">Pending Requests</a> <!-- item -->
          <a href="#" class="item">Forms</a>
          <a href="#" class="item">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class="header">
    <p class="pageTitle">User Management</p>
    <p>AMICO USER MANAGEMENT</p>
  </div>

  <div class="table-title">
    <div class="row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add User
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row pop-up">
    <button class="close-button">x</button>
    <div class="entry">
      <div class="form">
        <form action="/add-user" method="POST">
          <!-- cross-site request forgery -->
          @csrf

          @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            </div>
          @endif

          <label for="userId">User ID</label>
          <input class="inputForm" type=text id="userId" name="userId" required>

          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input class="inputForm" type=text id="name" name="name" required>

          <label for="pass">Password</label>
          <input class="inputForm" type=text id="pass" name="pass" required>

          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input class="inputForm" type=text id="email" name="email" required>

          <label for="contact_no">Contact Number</label>
          <input class="inputForm" type=text id="contact_no" name="contact_no" required>

          <label for="role">Role</label>
          <input class="inputForm" type=text id="role" name="role" required>

          <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="section section--large" id="part1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
          <div class="table-title">
            <h2>User Management</h2>
          </div>
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="user-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>UserID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Contact Number</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Edit or Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @if(isset($userId))
                <tr>
                  <td>User ID: {{ $userId }}</td>
                  <td>Name: {{ $user->name }}</td>
                  <td>Password: {{ $user->pass }}</td>
                  <td>Email: {{ $user->email }}</td>
                  <td>Contact Number: {{ $user->contact_no }}</td>
                  <td>Role: {{ $user->role }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ $user->userId }}">
                    <!-- Edit Button -->
                    <button class="btn btn-primary edit-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal" data-userid="{{ $user->userId }}">Edit</button>
                    <!-- Delete Button -->
                    <button class="btn btn-danger delete-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteUserModal" data-userid="{{ $user->userId }}">Delete</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              @elseif(isset($userData) && count($userData) > 0)
                @foreach($userData as $user)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->userId }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->pass }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->contact_no }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ $user->userId }}">
                      <!-- Edit Button -->
                      <button class="btn btn-primary edit-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal" data-userid="{{ $user->userId }}">Edit</button>
                      <!-- Delete Button -->
                      <button class="btn btn-danger delete-user" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteUserModal" data-userid="{{ $user->userId }}">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
              @else
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="7">No user data available</td>
                </tr>
              @endif
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <nav>
      <!-- Your navigation links here -->
      <a href="{{ route('admin/receiving_repo') }}" class="item1">Receiving Report</a>
      <a href="{{ route('admin/asset_info') }}" class="one" id="active_page">Asset Information</a>
      <a href="{{ route('admin/ack_repo') }}" class="item1">Acknowledgement Report</a>
      <a href="{{ route('admin/prop_borr') }}" class="item1">Property Borrowing</a>
      <a href="{{ route('admin/main_req') }}" class="item1">Maintenance Request</a>
      <a href="{{ route('admin/condemn_req') }}" class="item1">Condemnation Request</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Edit User Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="editUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editUserModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="editUserModalLabel">Edit User</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="{{ route('admin/users.update', $user->userId) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" required>

            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="{{ $user->pass }}" required>

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}" required>

            <label for="contact_no">Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="contact_no" name="contact_no" value="{{ $user->contact_no }}" required>

            <label for="role">Role</label>
            <input type="text" id="role" name="role" value="{{ $user->role }}" required>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Delete User Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteUserModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteUserModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteUserModalLabel">Confirm Deletion</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="pageTitle">Are you sure you want to delete this user?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <form action="{{ route('admin/users.delete', $user->userId) }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../res/js/asset_information.js"></script>
  <script src="../res/js/navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User; // Make sure to include the User model

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllUsers()
    {
        $users = User::all(); // Retrieve all users from the 'users' table

        return view('users', ['users' => $users]);
    }

    public function addUser(Request $req)
    {
        // Validate the input data
        $validatedData = $req->validate([
            'userId' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'pass' => 'required|min:6|max:24',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'contact_no' => 'required',
            'role' => 'required',
        ]);

        // Create a new user with the validated data
        $user = new User();
        $user->userId = $validatedData['userId'];
        $user->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $user->pass = $validatedData['pass'];
        $user->email = $validatedData['email'];
        $user->contact_no = $validatedData['contact_no'];
        $user->role = $validatedData['role'];

        // Add any other user attributes as needed

        $user->save();

        // Redirect to a success page or return a response
        return redirect()->route('admin/users')->with('success', 'User added successfully');
    }

    public function editUser(Request $request, $userId)
    {
        // Find the user by their ID
        $user = User::find($userId);

        if (!$user) {
            // Handle the case where the user doesn't exist
            return redirect()->route('admin/users')->with('error', 'User not found');
        }

        // Now that you have fetched the user data, you can proceed to update it.
        // Update the user attributes based on the form input
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->pass = $request->input('pass');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->contact_no = $request->input('contact_no');
        $user->role = $request->input('role');
        // Add similar lines for other fields you want to edit

        // Save the changes
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin/users')->with('success', 'User updated successfully');
    }

    public function deleteUser($userId)
    {
        // Find the user by their ID
        $user = User::find($userId);

        if ($user) {
            // Delete the user
            $user->delete();
            return redirect()->route('admin/users')->with('success', 'User deleted successfully');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('admin/users')->with('error', 'User not found');
        }
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php
    
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\InvController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::post('/loginpage', [InvController::class, 'showDashboard']);

Route::post('/rr_report', [InvController::class, 'addEntry']);

Route::post('/accept_request', [InvController::class, 'acceptRequest']);

Route::post('/decline_request', [InvController::class, 'declineRequest']);

Route::post('/edit_asset', [InvController::class, 'editAsset']);

Route::get('/admin/asset_info', function () {
    return view('/admin/asset_info');
});

Route::get('employee/asset_info', function () {
    return view('/employee/asset_info');
});

Route::post('/upload', [InvController::class, 'uploadCsvFile']);

Route::get('admin/receiving_repo', function () {
    $results = DB::select('select * from receiving_report where req_status = "accepted"');
    Log::info(count((array) $results));
    $results = (array) $results;
    Log::info($results);
    return view('admin/receiving_repo', compact('results'));
})->name('admin/receiving_repo');

Route::view('admin/ack_repo', 'admin/ack_repo')->name('admin/ack_repo');
Route::view('admin/prop_borr', 'admin/prop_borr')->name('admin/prop_borr');
Route::view('admin/main_req', 'admin/main_req')->name('admin/main_req');
Route::view('admin/calib_req', 'admin/calib_req')->name('admin/calib_req');
Route::view('admin/condemn_req', 'admin/condemn_req')->name('admin/condemn_req');
Route::view('admin/asset_info', 'admin/asset_info')->name('admin/asset_info');

Route::get('admin/pending', function () {
    $results = DB::select('select * from receiving_report where req_status = "pending" or req_status = "declined"');
    Log::info(count((array) $results));
    $results = (array) $results;
    Log::info($results);
    return view('admin/pending', compact('results'));
})->name('admin/pending');

Route::get('employee/pending', function () {
    $results = DB::select('select * from receiving_report where req_status = "pending" or req_status = "declined"');
    Log::info(count((array) $results));
    $results = (array) $results;
    Log::info($results);
    return view('employee/pending', compact('results'));
})->name('employee/pending');


Route::get('employee/receiving_repo', function () {
    $results = DB::select('select * from receiving_report where req_status = "accepted" ');
    Log::info(count((array) $results));
    $results = (array) $results;
    Log::info($results);
    return view('employee/receiving_repo', compact('results'));
})->name('employee/receiving_repo');

Route::view('employee/ack_repo', 'employee/ack_repo')->name('employee/ack_repo');
Route::view('employee/prop_borr', 'employee/prop_borr')->name('employee/prop_borr');
Route::view('employee/main_req', 'employee/main_req')->name('employee/main_req');
Route::view('employee/calib_req', 'employee/calib_req')->name('employee/calib_req');
Route::view('employee/condemn_req', 'employee/condemn_req')->name('employee/condemn_req');
Route::view('employee/asset_info', 'employee/asset_info')->name('employee/asset_info');
Route::view('employee/rr', 'employee/rr')->name('employee/rr');

//User Management
Route::get('admin/users', function () {
    // Add logic to fetch user data here
    $userData = DB::select('select * from users'); // Fetch all user data (modify this to fit your use case)

    return view('admin/users', ['userData' => $userData]); // Pass user data to the 'user' view
})->name('admin/users');

Route::post('/add-user', [UserController::class, 'addUser'])->name('addUser');

// Add a route for editing a user
Route::get('admin/users/edit/{userId}', function ($userId) {
    $user = DB::table('users')->find($userId);
    return view('admin.editUser', ['user' => $user]);
})->name('admin/users.edit');

// Process user update form
Route::post('admin/users/update/{userId}', [UserController::class, 'editUser'])
    ->where(['userId' => '[0-9]+'])
    ->name('admin/users.update');

// Add a route for deleting a user
Route::post('admin/users/delete/{userId}', [UserController::class, 'deleteUser'])
    ->where(['userId' => '[0-9]+'])
    ->name('admin/users.delete');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

Route::get('pdf', [PdfExtractorController::class, 'extractPdf']);

require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
```

I did try changing the buttons in this form but it didn't work:

```html
<a href="{{ route('admin/users.edit', ['userId' => $user->userId]) }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUserModal">
  Edit
</a>
```

Comment: You must provide a [mre] of your issue _within_ the question. External links are not allowed (in case they disappear in future). See the [help/on-topic] guidance, and also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. As you're new please also take the [tour]

Comment: Please help me with this T_T

Comment: You're pre-populating the modal with whatever was the last value of $user when your foreach loop ran. It's not being chosen dependent on which user the user selected. You need to use some JavaScript to get the user ID from the data attribute of the button, and then most likely you should get the rest of the data from the server on-demand via ajax based on that ID

Comment: `My post is mostly code`...yes because you seemingly didn't think about what is actually _needed_ for a [mre] of your issue. For example why do we need your entire route configuration code? At most 2 or 3 lines of web.php which point to the route/view where you're having this issue are going to be even slightly relevant for explaining the scenario. Don't just dump your entire codebase on us...that's really not useful (it's just clutter, and means it takes longer for us to work out what _is_ relevant, which slows down or reduces the help you can get), and thats why the site warned you about it